# Android: Content provider best practices

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I develop an Android app, and I need to use the SQLite database. So I have 2 possibilities to:

- To use Data Object Layer class: these class will use my Dbhelper and will do CRUD actions.
- To use ContentProvider

In this last case, should I create several ContentProvider according my different tables impacted in my SQLite database (not 1 COntentProvider for 1 Table, but maybe for a tables group?)

My application is to manage the athlete's sport workout.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if possible you should always use a `ContentProvider`. In previous Android versions it was more customary to use a DbHelper or DbManager to do CRUD operations but that has changed. `ContentProvider` already bring a lot of functionality with them that you wold otherwise have to write yourself and they do a lot of work for you e.g. thread safety etc.

As for your other question: Usually you only have one `ContentProvider` per app. Or it should at least be avoided to have more than one if it is possible and it fits into your requirements. One case where I would say more than one is justified would be if you have data which should not be accessible to other apps and other data which should be accessible to other apps.

Comment: Thanks Xaver for your reply! Is it necassary to have a layer above my ContentProvider like a Data Access Layer ? Coz I don't want to use Cursor notion in my code, except in DAL and Content Provider. What do you think about that, and about your experience ? Thank you so much :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is necessary but a little abstraction never hurt anybody and it makes it easier to work with the data if you don't have to concern yourself directly with Cursors, CursorLoaders etc. Personally I tend to use an ORM or write some kind of DAL to manage the data in the db.

Comment: I found this excellent tutorial: https://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/